# Find if child element of parent element exists

Tags: javascript, dom

I've searched for a while now, and thought if for nothing else, to document this case here for future users.

How do I find out if a certain element contains a certain child element in the DOM using plain javascript?  I have in my app an element with class 'react-tab'.  It will become hidden, and no longer 'react-tab' but 'react-tab hidden' when the tab is in the background.

I want to check if the active class 'react-tab' div contains a div with id="drawingDiv".

so something like:

```
if(document.getElementsByClass("react-tab").contains("drawingDiv"))
```

or

```
if(document.getElementsByClass("react-tab").childNodes.contains("drawingDiv"))
```

I have yet to get the right answer, I do not want to use jQuery.

Comment: As in immediate children?

Comment: yes, an immediate child.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you could use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for this.

```
var exists = !!document.querySelector(".react-tab:not(.hidden) > #drawingDiv");
```

Comment: Almost,  it works, but when the class changes to .react-tab hidden it still "exists"

Comment: oh maybe try `var exists = !!document.querySelector(".react-tab:not(.hidden) > #drawingDiv");`

Comment: AWESOME!.  You're the man.  The next guy may have a nice googleable answer.  I need to look into the querySelector logic.

Comment: @erikvold—you should add that comment to the answer, as it's actually the answer. ;-)